# What is the range of a soul cage?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I'm building an enclosure for my soul cage. How large should I make it such that no mobs escape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Soul_Cage

According to the wiki, 8x8x3 is the spawn area so just clear that large area and enclose it, which should keep all mobs inside.